# Flutter: How to return to a specific Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm having a problem right now in my flutter application. Specifically in my Bottom Navigation Bar. So in my navigation bar I have items which names are (Community, Feeds, My Activity, Profile). The problem I'm facing is in the "Feeds" because in my "Feeds" I have a card, and in that card I have a button named "View Profile", when I click the "View Profile" it redirects me to a new page and in that page it shows the "Profile" of the selected card. Now the problem is when I go back, when I click the "<-" logo in the page, it returns to the "Community" page the first navigation on my navigation bar.

Now the question is how can I return to my "Feeds" navigation when I click the "<-" logo. Please help.

My "Feeds" UI:

[image]

UI when "View Profile" is clicked:

[image]

My code when clicking the "View Profile" button:

```
onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => new OrgProfile(
                                    doc.data['Name of Organization'])));
                      },
```

My code on the new page when you click "View Profile":

```
    class _OrgProfileState extends State<OrgProfile> {
  @override
  final db = Firestore.instance;

  Container buildItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   return Container(
     child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 70,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        '${doc.data['Email']}',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
 }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.orgName)),
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: db
          .collection('USERS')
          .where('Name of Organization', isEqualTo: widget.orgName)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
              children: snapshot.data.documents
                  .map((doc) => buildItem(doc))
                  .toList());
        } else {
          return SizedBox();
        }
        }),
   );
   }
  }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?